# Template class with virtual member: linker error

Tags: c++, templates, abstract-class, template-specialization, virtual-functions

Consider the following code. A is an abstract, generic class; B both implements and specializes it. This code seems trivially correct to me, but for some reason I end up with strange linker errors.

```
template<typename T>
class A {
    public:
        virtual void f();
};

class B : public A<int> {
    public:
        void f() {};
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    auto b = new B();
    return 0;
}
```

gcc output:

```
/tmp/ccXG2Z8A.o:(.rodata._ZTV1AIiE[_ZTV1AIiE]+0x10): undefined reference to `A<int>::foo()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

clang output:

```
/tmp/l2-2a09ab.o: In function `main':
l2.cpp:(.text+0x35): undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned long)'
/tmp/l2-2a09ab.o:(.rodata._ZTI1AIiE[_ZTI1AIiE]+0x0): undefined reference to `vtable for __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info'
/tmp/l2-2a09ab.o:(.rodata._ZTI1B[_ZTI1B]+0x0): undefined reference to `vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info'
/tmp/l2-2a09ab.o:(.rodata._ZTV1AIiE[_ZTV1AIiE]+0x10): undefined reference to `A<int>::foo()'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: First of all A is not an abstract class. You should do: virtual void foo() = 0; to make it a pure virtual function

Comment: This was it, thanks. If you submit this as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: you should implement `A::f()` or make it pure virtual. If a virtual method is missing the linker cannot construct the virtual method table of `A`. So this message appears.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From gcc output, I'll assume that your function is called `foo` instead of just `f`.

The problem is that the class `A` is not abstract, because you haven't declared its method as such. You would do so in this way:

```
virtual void foo() = 0;
```

But you forgot the `= 0`, so the linker doesn't know that the method is abstract, and is therefore looking for a function body that is not there.

Answer (score 1):

A is not an abstract class. You should do:

```
virtual void f() = 0;
```

to make it a pure virtual function